# Arranging multiple board files in single board file

Tags: cadence, allegro

I am going for PCB array manufacturing in order to save some costs. I have totally designed 3 different board files and I want to combine each of them side by side.

Can somebody tell me the steps in achieving this?

I am using Allegro 16.6V

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I panelized multiple using replica option present in the allgero, although I had to do little bit of rework.

Answer (score 2):

I would ask the PCB shop to panelize the boards for me.  They will know their preferred panel sizes and required spacing between boards on the panel.

Comment: They have asked us to panelize the PCB and told to maintain at least of 350mil between mount holes of each PCB

Comment: @MightyBeard007, who is your board manufacturer?  I find it a little odd that a decent company would not be willing to panelise your boards for you, since they have tools that make this kind of thing trivial.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how software sees connections between schematic and layout. For example Altium Designer Cad treats boards not so strict and you can simply select all in one project (one board workspace) and copy it to another. On other side, Eagle CAD has very strict reverse annotation system (aka reverse annoyance system) which prevents these ungodly acts of creativity (copy/paste) from user. You can simply disable this annotation system and you are good to go "copy & paste"-ing to your heart´s content. Not sure how Allegro CAD sees this, but since it´s Cadence, it shouldn´t be simple. This is expensive software :-)

Once annotations are broken, you can copy and paste it as much as you like. All board files carry with them drill information and layout information so there is no problem in copy/pasting. That is true for Altium and Eagle, should be true for Allegro.

If you need more information, set a follow-up question.

Happy pasting...

(No reference for Allegro, both Altium and Eagle work process are from personal experince of around 5 years of work with both CAD packages)

Comment: what about gerbmerge?

Comment: First time heard about it. More of an old-poor-school man, myself. It could work, from what description in Github says. What I see as a potential problem - if your board house feels in mood to mess with you - distance between boards; should board panel have additional markings for pick and place; serial number of panel and such, then it is easier to open it in ECAD and correct it from there. All others options, in my opinion, seem more like drive-by solutions, patches not actual solutions. Hope it helps